# need to read excel sheet C# and import into mySQL only 3 columns

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to read 3 columns from an excel sheet and import them into a mySQL database. I am very new at C# and need as much detailed help as possible. The MySQL_DB_Management in my using block is a friend's class that basically serves to create my connection string. The code I have thus far is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using MySQL_DB_Management;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace Class_Code_Discrepancy
{
  public partial class CC_Disc_Fixer : Form
  {
    MySqlDB mysql;
    SqlConnection sql;

    public CC_Disc_Fixer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //create connection strings
        sql = new SqlConnection(@"server=1.1.1.1;" + @"Trusted_Connection=false;" + @"uid=RO_agent;" +
                                @"password=mypass;" + @"database=Depot;");
        mysql = new MySqlDB("1.1.1.1", "platform", "root", "password");
    }

private void Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        string excelconn = @"Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                                @"Data Source=c:\Notebook Classcode Master 20121024.xlsx;" +
                                @"Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;FirstRowHasNames=NO";
        OleDbConnection xlconn = new OleDbConnection(excelconn);

        //DataSet xldataset = new DataSet();
        //OleDbDataAdapter xladaptor = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        xlconn.Open();
        OleDbCommand sel = new OleDbCommand();
        sel.Connection = xlconn;
        DataTable dtsheet = xlconn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
    }
```

Any help on what I need to do next would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking into a [ExcelDataReader](https://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/) library, with that, you can read Excel file into a DataSet just as shown at their page.

```
FileStream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

//1. Reading from a binary Excel file ('97-2003 format; *.xls)
IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
//...
//2. Reading from a OpenXml Excel file (2007 format; *.xlsx)
IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
//...
//3. DataSet - The result of each spreadsheet will be created in the result.Tables
DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
//...
//4. DataSet - Create column names from first row
excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
```

Then you can iterate through it with foreach loop

```
foreach (DataTable dt in result.Tables)
{
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
           {
               // do something
           }
    }
}
```

And if you want to acces only first three columns, you can do it like

```
result.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];
result.Tables[0].Rows[0][1];
result.Tables[0].Rows[0][2];
```

Comment: I tried using this to no avail, i can't get past this exception: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll. Additional information: Could not find file blah blah.xlsx. The file is definitely there but it won't find it for some reason. I did some research on this but nothing i've found fixes it. any ideas?

Comment: How does your string `filePath` - path to string looks like ? Is it something like `string filePath = @"C:\Users\BlahBlah\Desktop\ExcelFile.xlsx";` ?

Comment: Ok fixed the filepath string and now it works. Now having a problem with #4 in your example. VS keeps erroring saying that i can't use the variable "result" a second time because it is already defined. Do i even need to do #4 at all to import into mysql?

Comment: since i am a beginner, i am trying to figure out what the foreach loops are doing and i'm unable to pinpoint it down. I inserted     MessageBox.Show(((result.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]).ToString()) + ((result.Tables[0].Rows[0][1]).ToString())); inside of the 3rd foreach loop to try and understand what is happening. the result i get combines those 2 cells together and repeats it for the length of the sheet.. i understand that much, but how do i get the total value of all cells in the sheet? I am trying to take all the values from 3 different columns and import them to a mysql database. please help!

Comment: 1) 3. and 4. are almost same, use 4. if you have column names as first row in your excel and you want them as column names in you DataTable, else use 3.
2) use `MessageBox.Show(dr[dc].ToString());` to show all rows, columns and their values from your table, if you use `MessageBox.Show(((result.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]).ToString()) + ((result.Tables[0].Rows[0][1]).ToString()));` you will just be getting the same two values over and over.

Comment: if you want to take values of three columns in first row, you can use `result.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]; result.Tables[0].Rows[0][1]; result.Tables[0].Rows[0][2];` outside of the loop.